# Dynamically load front from web to Angular : is it possible?

Tags: angular, dynamic, fonts

I need to be able to load fonts from a back-end server to style my text in Angular.
I have, stored in variable, the web URL of my font (example: 'website.com/myfont.ttf') and the name (in this case: 'myfont').

I also have a component with a `<label>` which has to be stylized with this custom font. Notice that my fonts come from a back-end, it has to be perfectly dynamic.
After spending hours looking for a solution and testing everything I found (FontFace, WebFontLoader, add-font, ...), I start thinking it may not be possible :(.

To summarize: my Angular app gets a list of fonts from my back-end's API as a JSON. It gets the fonts URL on the server and their name. I want to use the font chosen by the user and apply it to some elements (label, div, etc) dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

I have never done this before, but I would guess that the solution is to dynamically add and remove styles in your page `head`.

```
let fontName = ...; // Your font name
let fontUrl = ...; // The fully qualified url of your font

let style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerText = "@font-face { font-family: '" + fontName + "'; src: url('" + fontUrl + "'); }";
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

And then modify the style of your element, adding a `font-family` with the `fontName` you are loading.

As a side note, the `document` object is only available if you are sure to be running your angular app in a browser, and you import the `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` in the imports for your angular app. [See reference here](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT).

Disclaimer: directly modifying the DOM may go against angular principles, be warned.

Disclaimer2: the code above may open you up to security flaws (XSS). Best console the [angular security guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/security) to do it properly.

Answer (score -2):

In SCSS, you can use the `@font-face` decorator to define a cutom font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  src: url('assets/segoeuil.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```

Notice that in my example I used a static font file. If you want to query your back-end to return a font of its choice, simply create a dedicated endpoint, and than put its url here.

If you want your font to be subjective to the user, you'll need to add this information to the request. To do that you can use an `HttpInterceptor` (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) Which is a feature of angular enabling you to change any request that the client makes. A common practice is to add an authentication token to every request, this way your backend can determine the font subjective to the user and its data, and send that as an answer to the request.

Though this is possible, I would like to offer you an easier solution (in my opinion) - if you have a finite set of fonts, you can simply create them as static assets in the client server (put them in the `assets` folder) and than - in the client - determine which font to use, base on some information your got from back-end about the user. For example - create a css class for each font, and dynamically assign this class to your body element based on the "selected font".